# Unable to get responsive layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here's the live URL of my web page, however I'm using the latest version of bootstrap. All 'css' is included in 'master.css'. The problem is this box or any other(later on if you fill the form) is not responding to any responsiveness. Tried on mobile as well! What am I missing here?

http://mplanner.esy.es/mplanner/

I've included only bootstrap.min.css and some custom styles at the end in 'master.css'

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap - module for Angular?

Comment: I didn't get you! No I don't think so I've added anything specific

Comment: Add angular bootstrap UI to use Bootstrap with angular -> https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . I do not know if that fixes your current problem but you will get problems without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a fixed width to `.col-min` and to `.form-area-inner, .form-planner-inner`
Therefore, the "responsive"-width of bootstrap is being replaced by the fixed witdhs.

Removing those fixed-widths will give you back the responsiveness. You can use some media queries if you want to keep the fixed widths on layouts with a certain width.